# Sharing Costs for Train Travel Flatrate (BahnCard100)

Tags: germany, travel, law

My future employer is a 100€ (200€ return ticket) train tricket far away from where i am living.
They expect me to visit four times a year, so with return ticket that is at least 800€.

They already said they would like to see me even more often and that they would pay for all the travel costs.

There is a "train travel flatrate" card (called Bahn Card 100) where you can travel on every train for free - all year long. It currently costs 4.144€.

So if their Budget for my Visits (i.e. 6 Visits a year) is 1200€, is there a legal way for my employer and me to share the costs for the Bahn Card 100 instead of them paying full or paying for single rides?

Comment: This honestly sounds like something your future employer would be best placed to answer. They will know the law around travel expenses. Just be careful when asking to keep "how many times you're willing to come into the office" and "is it possible to share the expense so I get free train travel for a year" separate

Comment: I probably wouldn't mark my answer as accepted so early. Germans may know an even more standard way of doing this.

Comment: Where are you going? That's an expensive ticket. You can get Hamburg to Munich (800 km) for about 50 Euros leaving next Monday. The Bahncard 100 is also very expensive. A Bahncard 50 is only 234€. So if the real ticket price 150€ round trip and you get a BC 50, 8 round trips a year would cost 834€ total. I suggest doing a bit of data analysis and put a few scenarios in a spread sheet BEFORE asking your employer. You want to make sure you don't come across as incompetent or greedy.

Comment: Do you think 800 €/year is a lot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a legal way? Sure.

They give you a travel allowance, and you use it to offset the cost.

You should make sure you both agree to how often you will visit the office, and you stick to it.

There are probably more elaborate schemes that would avoid you getting taxed on the 800€. Maybe you can claim the 800€ as a tax deduction for example.

Comment: This really depends. For example, in The Netherlands, employers can give a tax-free reimbursement per traveled kilometer (both for car, public transport, going on foot or by bike), with all kinds of limits (maximised one-way distance, maximum per kilometer, etc). However, when you use public transport, you can exceed that default maximum, but you then have to declare the actual cost. I don't know the rules in Germany, but it is entirely possible that doing this would end up being more expensive for the OP than simply requesting reimbursement for individual tickets.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That is sort of the point. The easy legal way to do this is for the company to just pay OP however much they think is appropriate. The disadvantage is that this money would count as income and hence be taxed. There may be more elaborate schemes that avoid taxes but this is not covered in this answer.